# SQL Server BCP load data by using master.dbo.xp_cmdshell - Errors and server with multiple instances

Tags: sql-server, instance, loading, bcp

I get some errors when loading data from txt/csv file into SQL Server table:

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Answer (score 1):

Pre-condition: using BCP command need your user account has enough permission to that file folder, like create a file, edit a file or delete a file. And also the file is not opened when using it. For example, the sample code below, d:_temp will the the folder to check.

Note: When the server has multiple instances, like dev, test, preprod or prod, you will have to add @@Servername which will distinguish which instance is used to load data into.
eg: ServerName will be this format: DTC001\Dev, DTC001\Test

Here are the correct format to query out data or load data into table:

```
  --Load data from txt file into table:    
    Declare @sql varchar(8000) 
        Declare @FileName varchar(100) ='123out.txt'
        Declare @Path varchar(1000) ='d:\_temp\';
        if object_id('tempdb..##tt_test') > 0 drop table ##tt_test;    
        CREATE TABLE ##tt_test (FileLine VARCHAR(max));
        select @sql  = 'bcp ##tt_test in "' + @Path + @FileName + '" /c /t \n /k /S' + @@SERVERNAME + ' /T'
        --print @sql
        EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @sql;
        select * from ##tt_test
    
--queryout data into txt/csv file. successfully.
        declare @str varchar(8000) 
        Declare @FileName varchar(100) ='1234588.txt'
        Declare @Path varchar(1000) ='d:\_temp\';
        Declare @SelectCMD varchar(200) ='select top 10 col1 from testdb.dbo.table1';
        Set @str ='EXEC master..xp_Cmdshell ''bcp "' + @SelectCMD +'" queryout "' + @Path  + @FileName + '" -c -t"" -S' + @@servername + ' -T'''  
        Print @str
        EXEC(@str);
```

here are some popular errors I got when loading data from txt/csv file into SQL server table:

Error 1: Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file
Possible reasons: could not find the path or filename. I made a syntax error to use '' instead of double quote " which cause this error. see the sample code below. Please make sure you are using double quote for the file path.

```
Error command: EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'bcp ##tt_test in ''d:\_temp\123.txt'' -c -T';
```

Error 2: Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file
Possible reasons: the text file may not ending with correct symbol.
the 123out.txt is the one I use
Another popular reason is: The table columns do not match the txt/csv file will create this error also.
[image]